# Openlayers html5 canvas text bold one word

Tags: html5-canvas, openlayers

I am building an app that will allow users to add to text to a map. I am using Openlayers `ol.style.Text` to achieve this, see below:

```
text: new ol.style.Text({
  text: "Your text \n on a new line",
  textAlign: 'left',
  textBaseline: 'bottom',
  offsetX: 10,
  offsetY: -5,
  scale: 1.5,
  placement: 'point',
  font: '12px sans-serif',
  backgroundFill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)'
  }),
  backgroundStroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
    width: 1
  }),
  padding: [5,5,5,5]
})
```

I know that I can make all of the text bold by changing `font: '12px sans-serif'` to `font: 'bold 12px sans-serif'`

My question is: Is there a way I can make just one word bold ('line' for example)?

Comment: Related question (on gis.stackexchange.com): [Rendering ol.style.Text as HTML in OpenLayers 3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142129/rendering-ol-style-text-as-html-in-openlayers-3)